# Better having loops inside or outside tf.functions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I don't quite see in the TF documentation anything regarding loops and performances, so I wanted to know which one was better:

1. loop inside:

```
@tf.function
def f(iters):
   for i in tf.range(iters):
      ...
f(10)
```

2. loop outside:

```
@tf.function
def f():
  ...
for i in range(10):
  f()
```

In other words, will the conditional branching of the for loop hurt performance inside the graph?